# Proving convergence in probability

Tags: convergence

I'm looking at an example here: [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~romik/teaching-pages/mat235a-2013/discussion8.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Eromik/teaching-pages/mat235a-2013/discussion8.pdf) (2nd example below Lemma 5)

We have that $X_n$ converges in probability to 0. I'm looking at the bit where we show want to $X_n/(1+X_n)$ converges in $L^1$ to 0.

I do not understand how the author has bounded the expectation above by what is shown. I have tried to use Markov's inequality, but I can only bound it below.

Comment: You might be missing the fact that $|X_n|/(1+|X_n|) < 1$. This is important to getting the upper bound.

Comment: @fblundun so it is bounded above by 1, which is also $P(|X_n| > \epsilon) + P(|X_n| \leq \epsilon) $, but where does the term before $P(|X_n| \leq \epsilon)$ come from?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_n = \frac{|X_n|}{1+|X_n|}$. Then $Y_n$ is bounded above by 1.

For $\epsilon\gt0$,

$$
\begin{align}\mathbb{E}(Y_n)&\leq \left(\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\lt\epsilon)\sup_{|X_n|\lt\epsilon}Y_n\right) + \left(\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\ge\epsilon)\sup_{|X_n|\ge\epsilon}Y_n\right)\\&
\leq\left(\sup_{|X_n|\lt\epsilon}Y_n\right)+\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\geq\epsilon)\\
&= \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} + \mathbb{P}(|X_n|\geq\epsilon)\\
&\lt\epsilon + \mathbb{P}(|X_n|\geq\epsilon)
\end{align}
$$

The second term converges to 0 so this can be made arbitrarily small.